# TinyMCE 5 - Is there a way to accept only uploaded Image, using the "image" plugin?

Tags: tinymce

I want to allow *uploaded* images only, not images linked from external websites. Is there a way to only display the "Upload" section of the "image" plugin/dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image plugin does not have a built in configuration option to do what you want.  As TinyMCE is released under an open source license you could certainly modify the code of that plugin to get your desired outcome.